# How to exclude mask images while extracting images from PDF?

Tags: pdf, poppler

I have been using `pdfimages` to extract images from PDFs. It extracts all of following types of images

> image - an opaque image
>
> mask - a monochrome mask image
>
> smask - a soft-mask image
>
> stencil - a monochrome mask image used for painting a color or pattern

How can I extract only opaque type images and exclude mask, smask and stencil images?

Comment: Have you tried `man pdfimages`?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't find any option which get me what I required.

Answer (score 2):

I know that I'm late to the party, but here are my two cents:
1) Extract all the images (regular images and smask images) with pdfimages

```
pdfimages -j file.pdf images/image
```

2) Obtain the smask names and remove them (beward of the zero leading names)

```
pdfimages -list file.pdf  | grep smask | column -t|awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I '{}' printf "%03d\n" '{}' | xargs -I '{}' rm images/image-'{}'.ppm
```